# Getting XML error when installing SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, windows-7, sql-server-2012

Trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition on my laptop.

I keep getting an error about cannot write out the XML file.

> SQL Server setup encountered the following error. There was an error
>   generating the XML document. Error code 0X84B10001

I am running the setup.exe as administrator of the box.

What can I do to get around this please?

Comment: You could start by posting the actual error message so folks have some clue how to help you. We can't diagnose "an error about the XML file or something"...

Comment: I am not in front of my computer right now... but googling it revealed it..   "SQL Server setup encountered the following error. There was an error generating the XML document. Error code 0X84B10001".

Comment: This comment by me didn't mean I know the answer.  As I said I AM Administrator on my box.  That was the problem with the guy who had the posting before.  So Other options??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue.  I had no password on my computer.  I finally found the sql server error log and it was giving more detail about a Cryptographic Exception doing something with the registry.  I then added a password in, and now it's installed and working fine.

Crazy error, but I understand why you wouldn't want this situation.

Comment: Thanks for posting what you found, it was helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Tried this and other fixes. Apparently this error message applies to many different problems. What worked for me was to create a new user with admin privileges. Login as that user, then install.

Comment: In my case it was an issue with the user account I was using authenticating with the domain.  I logged out of local computer, back in, re-established new remote session, and problem went away.